# IEnumerable failed to set element

Tags: c#, api, ienumerable, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel that contains different elements inside different tables that I tend to assign to it by query.

My problem is that I can't do this with `IEnumerable` (in `GetAll()` below), it keeps returning me `null` for `RoomCode` but for a single item (in `GetDeviceId()` below) then it works fine.

```
public IEnumerable<DeviceViewModel> GetAll()
{
    var result = deviceRepository.GetAll().Select(x => x.ToViewModel<DeviceViewModel>());
    for(int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
    {
        int? deviceID = result.ElementAt(i).DeviceId;
        result.ElementAt(i).RoomCode = deviceRepository.GetRoomCode(deviceID);
    }
    return result;
}

public DeviceViewModel GetDeviceID(int deviceID)
{
    var result = new DeviceViewModel();
    var device = deviceRepository.Find(deviceID);
    if (device != null)
    {
        result = device.ToViewModel<DeviceViewModel>();
        result.RoomCode = deviceRepository.GetRoomCode(deviceID);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new BaseException(ErrorMessages.DEVICE_LIST_EMPTY);
    }
    return result;
}


public string GetRoomCode(int? deviceID)
{
    string roomCode;
    var roomDevice = dbContext.Set<RoomDevice>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeviceId == deviceID && x.IsActive == true);
    if (roomDevice != null)
    {
        var room = dbContext.Set<Room>().Find(roomDevice.RoomId);
        roomCode = room.RoomCode;
    }
    else
    {
        roomCode = "";
    }
    return roomCode;
}
```

Comment: First, you can use a `foreach` to enumerate the elements, that's the natural way to loop through an `IEnumerable`:

`foreach (var element in result)
{
    int? deviceID = element.DeviceId;
    element.RoomCode = deviceRepository.GetRoomCode(deviceID);
}`

Second, check that the type of each element is a `class` (reference type) and not a `struct`(value type).

Comment: Try to debug your code and put a breakpoint in the `GetRoomCode` function, to check what happened, and what is returned. Maybe the problem is in your data, we can't see that, but you can.

Comment: I try foreach and now it give me "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first". Also I have debug and my GetRoomCode work fine but I can't assign it to IEnumerable RoomCode. I have test it with a single item and my function GetRoomCode() work okay.

Comment: So if I understand well, the code in `GetDeviceID` works fine, but not the one in `GetAll`. I can see that `GetAll` calls `GetRoomCode` with the value of the field / property `DeviceViewModel.DeviceId`. The function `GetDeviceID` calls `GetRoomCode` with the value already as an argument, so maybe it's worth checking that the deviceId is properly populated in the viewmodel.

Comment: Everything work okay. I set my viewmodel item to public. I can get element item value but I can't set it.

Comment: To get rid of the error when using `foreach`, add `ToList()` to materialize the query `var result = deviceRepository.GetAll().Select(x => x.ToViewModel<DeviceViewModel>()).ToList();`

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the cause now, I wrote a proper answer, feel free to upvote / accept  if this solved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to materialize the query to a collection in local memory. Otherwise, the `ElementAt(i)` will query the db and give back some kind of temporary object each time it is used, discarding any change you do.

```
var result = deviceRepository.GetAll()
    .Select(x => x.ToViewModel<DeviceViewModel>())
    .ToList(); // this will materialize the query to a list in memory

// Now modifications of elements in the result IEnumerable will be persisted.
```

You can then go on with the rest of the code.

Second (and probably optional), I also recommend for clarity to use `foreach` to enumerate the elements. That's the C# idiomatic way to loop through an `IEnumerable`:

```
foreach (var element in result)
{
    int? deviceID = element.DeviceId;
    element.RoomCode = deviceRepository.GetRoomCode(deviceID);
}
```